# how to replace a sed expression (change and print only matched line) with a perl expression?

Tags: sed, regular-expression, perl

I am trying to move to perl (from sed). But how can I replace this sed expression with perl in a similarly short way?

```
sed -n '/patternmatch/s%stuff%changed%p' file
```

I need to search for a pattern, and only when the pattern is found, substitute "stuff" with "changed".

The only way I could do it was with an if statement which looks like this

```
perl -ne 'if ( /patternmatch/ ) { s%stuff%changed%; print }' file
```

Is it possible to do it as short as with sed? How?

PS: How to do it with `python` is [here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/216319/31673)

Comment: Just because it's Perl doesn't mean you *have* to make it shorter and less readable.

Comment: @Gilles: Of course not. My next step will be to change from perl and shell-scripting in general to python, which is said to be more readable and less complicated.

Comment: sed, having single character command names, will probably win the golf match.

Answer (score 10):

Use the modifier form of `if`:

```
perl -ne 's/stuff/changed/, print if /patternmatch/'
```

or, you can use `and` and `or` for flow control:

```
perl -ne '/patternmatch/ and s/stuff/changed/, print'
```

Comment: The latter is an interesting example of the precedence difference between `and` and `&&`.

Comment: For the speed (with a text file of several hundred megabytes on a ramdrive): My sed command took `real 9.919s`, my if(){}-perl command took `real  3.527s`, your print-if-perl command took `real 3.506s` and your and-perl command took `real 3.998s`. This was reproducible. That means the **print-if-variant is the fastest.**

Comment: @erik Actually, it just means you don't understand what you're measuring.  The relative speed of the two versions above depend on how many times `/stuff/` matches, and how many times `/patternmatch/` matches.  Also, if you really need speed, you can still speed things up by adding an `/o` flag to both regexps.

Comment: @lcd047: IIRC, `/o` matters only if there's dynamic stuff in the pattern.

Comment: @choroba `/o` means "compile the regexp only once, and take time to optimise it".  This makes a big difference if you have to match a lot of strings against the same regexp, but of course it breaks with dynamic patterns.  Also `/o` has some unexpected side-effects, which is why it has a reputation of being perpetually broken.  But if you use it properly it's quite nice.

Comment: @lcd047: My point was `/o` is automatic if the regex can't change.

Comment: @choroba I don't think the regexp is compiled only once if it doesn't change.  Or if it is, it's a relatively recent optimisation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/550258/1030675

Comment: flip-flop magic: `perl -ne 'print if /patternmatch/..(s/stuff/changed/,1)'` :)

Answer (score 1):

## *'s/abc/xyz/'*

```
user@unix:~$ echo 'abc' | sed      's/abc/xyz/'
xyz   

user@unix:~$ echo 'abc' | perl -pe 's/abc/xyz/'
xyz
```

```
user@unix:~$ echo 'abc' > file.txt && cat file.txt
abc
```

```
user@unix:~$ sed      's/abc/xyz/' file.txt
xyz   

user@unix:~$ perl -pe 's/abc/xyz/' file.txt
xyz
```

---

## *'s/patternmatch/stuffchanged/'*

```
user@unix:~$ echo 'patternmatch' | sed      's/patternmatch/stuffchanged/'
stuffchanged   

user@unix:~$ echo 'patternmatch' | perl -pe 's/patternmatch/stuffchanged/'
stuffchanged
```

```
user@unix:~$ echo 'patternmatch' > file.txt && cat file.txt
patternmatch
```

```
user@unix:~$ sed      's/patternmatch/stuffchanged/' file.txt
stuffchanged   

user@unix:~$ perl -pe 's/patternmatch/stuffchanged/' file.txt
stuffchanged
```