# how to replace a sed/perl expression (change and print only matched line) with a python expression?

Tags: sed, regular-expression, python, perl, python3

I have asked [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/216304/31673) to learn how `perl` could replace `sed`.

Now I want to know how the following commands (which do the same thing) would look like for `python`:

```
sed -n '/patternmatch/s%stuff%changed%p' file

perl -ne 'if ( /patternmatch/ ) { s%stuff%changed%; print }' file
```

Is it possible to write it as a one-liner? Alternative?

Comment: Probably, but `python` isn't designed for one liners like `perl` is. It doesn't have a flag to automatically consume `stdin` and process it.

Comment: You're going the *wrong* direction. For whatever reason, it appears you are attempting to replace the more simple/efficient matcher w/ something more complicated. That is *not* representative of good programming practice - why complicate what is already simple? A better goal might be to round-up all *invocations* of `sed` and concentrate them whereever possible into a single *(if you must)* Python call on `sed`. But sometimes many `sed`s *are* better where one will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for fun:

```
python -c 'import sys,fileinput,re;sys.stdout.writelines(re.sub("stuff", "changed", l, 1) for l in fileinput.input() if re.search("patternmatch", l))' file
```

Don't do it:) Use `sed`/`perl`/`awk`

Comment: I've forgot about `import a,b,c`. Thanks to @n-st. minus 14 characters.

Answer (score 2):

Let's do this using a simple example, consider for a file, we will replace each digit of a line with the string `HELLO`, if the line does not have any digit then leave it as it is :

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import re
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search(r'\d', line):
            print re.sub(r'\d', 'HELLO', line).rstrip('\n')
        else:
            print line.rstrip('\n')
```

**Test :**

```
$ cat file.txt 
foo bar test
spam 1 egg 5

$ python script.py 
foo bar test
spam HELLO egg HELLO
```

The same using `sed` :

```
$ sed '/[[:digit:]]/s/[[:digit:]]/HELLO/g' file.txt 
foo bar test
spam HELLO egg HELLO
```

Lets check the `time` stat :

```
$ time sed '/[[:digit:]]/s/[[:digit:]]/HELLO/g' file.txt 
foo bar test
spam HELLO egg HELLO

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.001s

$ time python script.py 
foo bar test
spam HELLO egg HELLO

real    0m0.017s
user    0m0.007s
sys 0m0.010s
```

As you can see using native text processing tools (`sed`, `awk` etc) would be your best bet in such circumstances.

Comment: I like [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/fileinput.html). You can write `for line in fileinput.input()` and run your script as `script.py`, `script.py f1 f2`, `script.py f1 - f2`

Comment: @EvgenyVereshchagin Thanks..as there is only one file involved here i think normal procedure will suffice..

Comment: There is a problem with `rstrip`. You remove all whitespaces at the end of the line. For example '1b2<space><space>' -> 'HELLObHELLO'. Use `rstrip('\n')` or `print s,`

Comment: @EvgenyVereshchagin This is only to give the idea..anyway edited..